# Initializing Structs in a Vector

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

How would I go about initializing a vector of struct instances in C++? For example, if I had:

```
    struct node {int a; int b;};
    int main() {
        std::vector<node> V {node node1, node node2...};
    }
```

How can I go about initializing the nodes in the vector in the declaration? Is this possible? I am using C++11 with initializer lists but am confused as to how they work, if they can be applied here.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct node {int a; int b;};
int main() {
    std::vector<node> V {{1,2}, {3,4}, ...};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

   struct node {int a;};

   int main() {
       std::vector<node> V {node{1}, node{2}};
   }
```